# Can I use a reverse relationship in a django-autocomplete-light search filter?

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

The field I need to search in belongs to a reverse 'diariaviagem' to 'viagem' relationship

```
class DiariaViagem(models.Model):
    viagem = models.ForeignKey(Viagem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fonte_pagamento = models.ForeignKey(FontePagamento, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ViagemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (FonteFilter,)
```

filter

```
class FontePagamentoViagemChangeListAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    model = FontePagamento

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(Q(diariaviagem__fonte_pagamento__codigo__icontains=self.q) | Q(
                diariaviagem__fonte_pagamento__descricao__icontains=self.q))
        return qs

class FonteFilter(FilterSelect2):
    title = 'Fonte de pagamento'                    # filter's title
    field_name = 'diariaviagem_set__fonte_pagamento'           # field name - ForeignKey to Country model
    autocomplete_url = 'fonte_pagamento_viagem_change_list_autocomplete' # url name of Country autocomplete view
    is_placeholder_title = False
    widget_attrs = {'data-placeholder': 'Selecione'}
```

The code displays the following error:

```
type object 'Viagem' has no attribute 'diariaviagem_set__fonte_pagamento'
```

If I just pass 'diariaviagem_set' or a property it returns:

```
'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get_queryset'
```

Can I do something like this?